# Journey builder Contacts status = ContactAttempted

Tags: marketing-cloud, contact, journeybuilder

Im testing a Journey, but my test user seems stuck. Im getting the Status of ContactAttempted, but i can find no documentation on what this means. Does anyone know this?

[image]

Comment: Really, no one to help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Salesforce:

> ContactAttempted is logged when an event is detected. It is followed
>   by InteractionEventHandled, which indicates that one of the event
>   handlers in the entry router was able to process that event (tie that
>   event to one or more journeys). From there it would go to
>   EventQueuedForProcessing, indicating that contact for that event is
>   queued for processing in that journey. It's possible to have an event
>   fire for which there are no published journey versions (nothing
>   listening to the event). In those situations, you would still see the
>   ContactAttempted message, but probably none of the other log messages.

In other words, something blew up deep in their internal processing, which means your Journey is not properly configured.  I received this when I changed DE's on an existing Journey - had to look at the JSON to see what we really being saved back to SMC.  The issue:  handlebar properties that evaluated to null at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the [Status Key Reference page](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/journey_builder_administration/status_key_reference/). Unfortunately, that Key is not part of the list.  I suggest you contact MC support.

Comment: Please paste the relevant paragraphs of your link here. Links go dead all the time and we do not want to lose the information.

Answer (score 1):

Their docs may have changed from one of the earlier answers, but it really just looks like an acknowledgement that an event was received (ex: an APIEvent). Further processing will result in more statuses being logged.

> An event was detected, but not yet processed. If an active journey uses the event, Journey Builder queues the contacts to enter the journey. If no active journey uses the event, this terminal status shows for this instance of the event.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_status_key_reference.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

You can also get ContactAttempted if you are using a Salesforce Data Entry Source and have the Journey in Test instead of Active; SF Data Entry Sources won't work in test.